# Conditionally format unique rows in a pivot table, and transfer this formatting to other cells without the rules or values

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, conditional-formatting

I have a pivot table which summarizes three key figures for each individual item in our inventory over a six week time frame.

I want to conditionally format with a color scale the six cells in the "Supplier Inventory DOH" rows for each individual item.
Once those six cells are formatted, I want to copy those colors to the coordinating six cells below in "Total Inventory" without the rules or values which come with the formatting typically.
The purpose of this is to show the Days on Hand risk by color scale, in coordination with the current inventory - think of it as layering formatting on top of the inventory values.

For the formatting process alone I found a similar related discussion referencing this article: [Excel conditional colour scale for multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51991016/excel-conditional-colour-scale-for-multiple-rows), and I tried using the code it included in the comments. I changed the code and its references to match what I would need- knowing full well that this code is meant just for a blanket drag and drop over all of the data-not for the unique rows themselves. If this code worked I hoped it would be a start at least- however after running it through it didn't do anything. I am wondering if some of this code is incorrect, what kind of code I would add in to only format the rows with the Supplier Inventory DOH description, or if there was a better way to do this?
For the copying formatting piece, I found a related article discussion: [How to copy the conditional formatting without copying the rules from a Conditional Formatted cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548156/how-to-copy-the-conditional-formatting-without-copying-the-rules-from-a-conditio), however copy and pasting just the color themselves did not work on my Windows 10 excel version. Is there a way to do this process as well?

Original version of code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ApplyConditionalFormatting()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' change to your sheet here
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    For rw = 3 To 8 ' change to your respective rows
        With ws
            Set rng = .Range(.Cells(rw, "E"), .Cells(rw, "K")) ' change to your respective columns

            With rng
                .FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
                .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority  ' now its index is 1, in case there already was cond formatting applied
            End With

            With rng.FormatConditions(1)
                With .ColorScaleCriteria(1)
                    .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
                    .Value = 0
                    .FormatColor.Color = 7039480
                End With

                With .ColorScaleCriteria(2)
                    .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
                    .Value = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$D$" & rw & "*3" ' References column D, change as needed
                    .FormatColor.Color = 8711167
                End With

                With .ColorScaleCriteria(3)
                    .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
                    .Value = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$D$" & rw & "*5" ' References column D, change as needed
                    .FormatColor.Color = 8109667
                End With
            End With
        End With
    Next rw
End Sub
```

My version of the code:

```
Sub CF()
'
' CF Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+f
'
End Sub

Public Sub Formatting()
Option Explicit
Sub ApplyConditionalFormatting()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    For rw = 6 To 1764
        With ws
            Set rng = .Range(.Cells(rw, "B"), .Cells(rw, "G"))

            With rng
                .FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
                .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
            End With

            With rng.FormatConditions(1)
                With .ColorScaleCriteria(1)
                    .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
                    .Value = 40
                    .FormatColor.Color = 7039480
                End With

                With .ColorScaleCriteria(2)
                    .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
                    .Value = 70
                    .FormatColor.Color = 8711167
                End With

                With .ColorScaleCriteria(3)
                    .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
                    .Value = 80
                    .FormatColor.Color = 8109667
                End With
            End With
        End With
    Next rw
End Sub
End Sub
```

I expect the rows for each individual items DOH to be conditionally formatted based on the rule I need in an automated process that doesn't include going row by row with format painter. Then, to be able to copy those colors to the Total Inventory cells below (without the rules or values) to be able to show the correlation between Days on Hand and what is left in the inventory.

Pivot Table with Rule:
[image: Pivot Table with Rule]

Pivot table with desired formatting:
[image: Pivot table with desired formatting]

Comment: I just added an additional answer. Please consider to mark the better one as "accepted answer" as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You can get all relevant cells by `PivotSelect`,
then add your desired conditional formatting to them,
and use the resulting `DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` as `Interior.Color` for your "Total Inventory" cells.

```
Private Sub ConditionalFormattingforSNCPlanning()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim pt As Excel.PivotTable
    Dim fc As Excel.FormatCondition
    Dim cs As Excel.ColorScale
    Dim strDOH As String, strTotal As String
    Dim rngSource As Range, rngDest As Range, rngCell As Range, strDest() As String

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables(1)
    strDOH = "'SNC PLANNING' 'Supplier Network DOH'"
    strTotal = "'SNC PLANNING' 'Total Inventory'"

    ' Delete all conditional colors and normal interior colors first
    With pt.TableRange2
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        .Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    End With

    ' Show all pivottable rows, as otherwise PivotSelect may fail
    Dim i As Long
    For i = pt.RowFields.Count To 2 Step -1
        pt.RowFields(i).ShowDetail = True
    Next i

    ' select all desired rows for conditional formatting
    pt.PivotSelect _
        Name:=strDOH, _
        Mode:=XlPTSelectionMode.xlDataOnly, _
        Usestandardname:=True

    ' if you don't want to delete every conditional format
    ' by above pt.TableRange2.FormatConditions.Delete
    ' then use following line here instead
    ' Selection.FormatConditions.Delete

    ' Add a new conditional formatting (3-Color Scale)
    Set cs = Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale(ColorScaleType:=3)
    With cs.ColorScaleCriteria(1)
        .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
        .Value = 40
        .FormatColor.Color = RGB(248, 105, 107) ' 7039480
        .FormatColor.TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With cs.ColorScaleCriteria(2)
        .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
        .Value = 70
        .FormatColor.Color = RGB(255, 235, 132) ' 8711167
        .FormatColor.TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With cs.ColorScaleCriteria(3)
        .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
        .Value = 80
        .FormatColor.Color = RGB(99, 190, 123) ' 8109667
        .FormatColor.TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    ' Get both ranges for later color-copy-code
    Set rngSource = Selection
    pt.PivotSelect _
        Name:=strTotal, _
        Mode:=XlPTSelectionMode.xlDataOnly, _
        Usestandardname:=True
    Set rngDest = Selection

    ' Exit if both range's cell count not equal
    If rngSource.Cells.Count <> rngDest.Cells.Count Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, this works only, if cell count is identical"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' store all addresses of the destination range's cells
    ReDim strDest(1 To rngDest.Cells.Count)
    i = 1
    For Each rngCell In rngDest.Cells
        strDest(i) = rngCell.AddressLocal
        i = i + 1
    Next rngCell

    ' copy source's DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    ' to destination's Interior.Color
    ' cell by cell
    i = 1
    For Each rngCell In rngSource.Cells
        ws.Range(strDest(i)).Interior.Color = rngCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        i = i + 1
    Next rngCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Asger- this was exactly what I needed! You are a blessing! I had a somewhat different code- and I was also confused about the color copy process of using ColorOfCF- but your code aligns everything very well. This is insurmountably appreciated!

Comment: Actually I ran into some issues with the code-because the cells have to match exactly for the code to work- (many times we get cells that don't have all of the keyfigure points) when I upload new data into our raw data sheet, it ends up erring out because the numbers do not match. My team is trying to incorporate a loop instead- but we are not quite sure how that would fit in to loop through all of the cells in the pivot, but in the loop have it loop through the cell-1?

Comment: Or, code in to cancel the copy color process for an item if it's missing one of the key figures "Network Inventory DOH"

Comment: In my example `PivotSelect` selects all rows of "Supplier Network DOH" and then all rows of "Total Inventory" (or "Network Inventory DOH" or what else is desired). Let's call that row pairs. If the second row of the pair is missing, then of course you can't copy the color from the first row to it. I just added a second answer with a loop-solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach with a loop over the `PivotTable.RowRange`. When the desired terms are found, the corresponding row of the `PivotTable.DataBodyRange` is coloured.

The "Source" (e. g. "Supplier Network DOH") is formatted via conditional formatting and the "Destination" (e. g. "Total Inventory") gets the displayed color of the previously conditional formatted row as interior color.

```
Private Sub ConditionalFormattingforSNCPlanningVersion2()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim pt As Excel.PivotTable
    Dim fc As Excel.FormatCondition
    Dim cs As Excel.ColorScale
    Dim SourceString As String, DestString As String
    Dim SourceIsFound As Boolean
    Dim SourceRow As Long, DestRow As Long
    Dim CellInColumn As Range, CellInRow As Range

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables(1)
    SourceString = "Supplier Network DOH"
    DestString = "Total Inventory"

    ' Delete all conditional colors and normal interior colors first
    With pt.TableRange2
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        .Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    End With

    ' Show all pivottable rows
    Dim i As Long
    For i = pt.RowFields.Count To 2 Step -1
        pt.RowFields(i).ShowDetail = True
    Next i

    ' loop all cells in last column of rowrange
    For Each CellInColumn In pt.RowRange.Columns(pt.RowRange.Columns.Count).Cells

        ' If row is source, then add conditional formatting
        If CellInColumn.Value = SourceString Then
            SourceIsFound = True
            SourceRow = CellInColumn.Row
            Set cs = Intersect(ws.Rows(SourceRow).EntireRow, pt.DataBodyRange).FormatConditions.AddColorScale(ColorScaleType:=3)
            With cs.ColorScaleCriteria(1)
                .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
                .Value = 40
                .FormatColor.Color = RGB(248, 105, 107) ' 7039480
                .FormatColor.TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            With cs.ColorScaleCriteria(2)
                .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
                .Value = 70
                .FormatColor.Color = RGB(255, 235, 132) ' 8711167
                .FormatColor.TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            With cs.ColorScaleCriteria(3)
                .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
                .Value = 80
                .FormatColor.Color = RGB(99, 190, 123) ' 8109667
                .FormatColor.TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If

        ' If cell is destination, then copy color of previously found sourcerow
        If CellInColumn.Value = DestString Then
            If SourceIsFound Then
                DestRow = CellInColumn.Row
                For Each CellInRow In Intersect(ws.Rows(SourceRow).EntireRow, pt.DataBodyRange).Cells
                    ws.Cells(DestRow, CellInRow.Column).Interior.Color = CellInRow.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
                Next CellInRow
                SourceIsFound = False
            End If
        End If

    Next CellInColumn
End Sub
```